# Как найти число в строке python?

Tags: python

Нужно в строке похожая на

```
1A3BCF

2BNKLOPY5T
```

найти числа.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
import re

re.findall('(\d+)', '2BNKLOPY5T')
```

Answer (score 4):

[re](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html)

Answer (score 3):

```
s = "1A3BCF 2BNKLOPY5T"
for i in filter( str.isdigit , s) : print(i)
```

сработает только для одиночных символов

Answer (score 0):

```
list_num = []
for i in 'bla23bla1bla8bla2':
    try:
        num = int(i)
        list_num.append(num)
    except ValueError:
        continue
print(list_num)
```

Comment: 1. try-catch :( 2. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/453060/178988